# Proxy over a proxy in linux

Tags: linux, proxy, vpn, squid

How to use two proxies with authentication in a linux terminal?

My college uses cyberroam with squid proxy server and it blocks all legitemate terminal requests such that basic commands like apt-get install libvirt kvm dont work.

So i was thinking of either running a vpn or a private proxy server on google app engine and connecting to it via the terminal but i need to go through the squid proxy to reach the internet.

Any ideas as to how to implement this.

PS: We already tried reasoning with the college authorities they say they cant help directly but we can always bypass it wihtout their knowing. And we really need this for our project so please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if NTLMAPS will work for you but it works for me on bypassing company proxy with the use of public proxy servers.

Another thing, my friend's company is using domain controller to authenticate internet users and he told me that NTLMAPS also works for him and able to access the net via linux terminal.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I setup the proxy in my ubuntu machine as below:

```
https://gopukrish.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/configure-proxy-in-ubuntu-14-04/
```

Following are the contents in-case the link becomes unusable in future.
Download and install cntlm package from  : http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/

Edit /etc/cntlm.conf

Give credentials in the below fields

username
domain
password
proxy  IP:Port
Note down the Listen port… say it is 3128
save

Select Network options in Ubuntu and choose network proxy
Give 127.0.0.1 port 3128 for all the protocols
/etc/init.d/cntlm restart
This worked for me after the restart